# Loop through map of lists to create DNS records for multiple domains in one resource block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I have several domains and I want to create subdomains with as much DRY as possible. This is the original structure:

```
variable "domain1" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["www", "www2"]
}

variable "domain2" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["www3", "www1"]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {
  for_each = toset(var.domain1)
  
  type = "A"
  name = "${each.key}.domain1.com"
  zone_id = ""
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "domain2" {
  for_each = toset(var.domain2)
  
  type = "A"
  name = "${each.key}.domain2.com"
  zone_id = ""
}
```

that I want to combine to one variable and one resource block:

```
variable "subdomains" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "domain1.com" = ["www", "www2"]
    "domain2.com" = ["www3", "www1"]
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {
  for_each = var.subdomains // make magic happen here...
  
  type = "A"
  name = "${each.subdomain_part}.${each.domain_part}" // ...and here
  zone_id = ""
}
```

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: If you have two different domains `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`, I assume they have two different `zone_id` too, right? So I think to generalize this you'd need some way to know or dynamically generate the zone ID, in order to achieve a complete working solution. 

Comment: That's the easy part though. Just a loop through aws_route53_zone data resource using the same variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925965/loop-through-map-of-lists-to-create-dns-records-for-multiple-domains-in-one-reso/69933397#comment123615964_69926283) about a messy state, I would not say messy... but certainly there are some downsides, the index in that answer is numeric, a plan show that the resource ends up:

```
  # aws_route53_record.domain1["0"] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {

  # aws_route53_record.domain1["1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {
```

That can create problems when we add or remove subdomains to the list, the order can change and that will cause the resources to be destroyed and recreated, not ideal on route53 records...

---

Here is another approach that will create a different index in the resource name.
We still use flatten to extract the subdomains but on this case I'm concatenating right away, that local variable is ready for the `aws_route53_record` resource to consume it.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

variable "subdomains" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "domain1.com" = ["www", "www2"]
    "domain2.com" = ["www3", "www1"]
  }
}

locals {
  records = flatten([for d, subs in var.subdomains: [for s in subs: "${s}.${d}"]])
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {
  for_each = toset(local.records)

  type    = "A"
  name    = each.value
  zone_id = "us-east-1"
}
```

A terraform plan of that looks like:

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_route53_record.domain1["www.domain1.com"] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {
      + allow_overwrite = (known after apply)
      + fqdn            = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = "www.domain1.com"
      + type            = "A"
      + zone_id         = "us-east-1"
    }

  # aws_route53_record.domain1["www1.domain2.com"] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {
      + allow_overwrite = (known after apply)
      + fqdn            = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = "www1.domain2.com"
      + type            = "A"
      + zone_id         = "us-east-1"
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can flatten your `var.subdomains` as follows:

```
locals {
    subdomains_flat = flatten([for domain, subdomains in var.subdomains:
                        [ for subdomain in subdomains:
                            {
                                domain_part = domain
                                subdomain_part = subdomain
                            }
                        ]
                      ])
}
```

then:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "domain1" {
  for_each = {for idx, val in local.subdomains_flat: idx => val }
  
  type = "A"
  name = "${each.value.subdomain_part}.${each.value.domain_part}" 
  zone_id = ""
}
```

Comment: That works, but creates quite a messy state because the index is used in resource name. Is it possible to tweak it so the subdomain is used in the resource name?

Comment: @aardbol the index must be unique, there is no guarantee that subdomains will be unique, instead of the subdomains_flat array you can build a custom map that suits your needs for a better looking index